# IIS URL Rewrite cache JSON Server Data

Tags: node.js, iis, json-server

I have an API (JSON Server) hosted on Windows RDP and I'm using URL rewrite IIS to get the JSON Data from the fake REST API also using the IIS to host my front end, the issue is every time someone joined the website the URL rewrite send a request to the JSON Server. any workaround to cache the data instead of overloading my Node JSON Server from the GET request.

Otherwise if there's anyway to send data to another linux server, cache it and using 2nd API also it will help.

Comment: ARR memory cache default is just 5 seconds, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/configure-and-enable-disk-cache-in-application-request-routing

Comment: thanks lexi that would really help ^^